# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'about'

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am new in Angular2 + Nativescript + TypeScript and I am trying to reproduce my cordova app. I am trying to navigate from Login page to About page, and I get this error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'about'
```

In my `app.routes.ts` file I have this code:

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: "/login",
        pathMatch: "full"
    },
    {
        path: "about",
        redirectTo: "/about",
        pathMatch: "full"
    }
];
```

Then, in my login.component.ts, I try to navigate to the about page using the router instance:

```
this.router.navigate(["/about"]);
```

Then I get the error message. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
        path        : "about",
        redirectTo  : "/about",
        pathMatch   : "full"
}
```

Change it to or add it,

```
{
        path        : "about",
        component   : AboutComponent    //<====whatever component you have. Maybe the relevant component is not found
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that, this is what I get: Component AboutComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

Comment: Okay. For that more code is need. where you use router-outlet?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio and Telerik AppBuilder tool, it creates multiple files in the app folder: app.component.ts, app.modules.ts, app.routes.ts, main.ts. I guess the router-outlet you are asking is in the app.component.ts:

@Component({
  selector: "ns-main",
  template: "<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>",
})

Comment: Did you put AboutComponent in "delarations" array of NgModule ?

Comment: @TrongLamPhan That was the part I was missing, thanks!